# PhpStorm highlighting and mis-formatting JS

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

I have the following code as part of a JS function on `Highcharts Highmaps`

```
map.series.map((el, i) => {
    el.data.map((e, j) => {
       if(e.code == ctry) {
            map.series[i].data[j].update({color: preHoverColor});
            map.series[i].data[j].setState();
            map.tooltip.hide();
        }
    })
})
```

PhpStorm is highlighting this code as error at `=>` with `expression expected`.

Is there a setting I missed in PhpStorm for JS syntax so this code is recognised as valid? The code works OK.

Comment: 1) It's not PHP code but JavaScript ... so I have no idea why `php` tag was used. 2) What JavaScript language version is selected at `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript`. It has to be one that supports arrow functions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have `ECMAScript 6` selected as **Javascript language version** in **Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript**

Answer (score 0):

many reasons of such scratching misbehavior in IDE

**Solution 1:** Webstorm > Preferences > Languages and Frameworks -> Javascript > ECMA Script6

IMPORTANT NOTE: do NOT go to Languages and Frameworks from File > Default Settings

**Solution 2:** Same goes for PHPStorm, but what I realized is the errors were being generated from JSHint.  It looks like PHPStorm/WebStorm do not sync the version to JSHint.

Under Code Quality Tools > JSHint, make sure "EcmaScript.next esnext" is checked.

**Solution 3:** Most likely the node_modules folder is added to javascript libraries (WebStorm prompts you to configure a library on project opening). Javascript files in libraries have the inspections and error/syntax highlighting turned off by default. You can still enable them for the particular file using the Hector icon in the lower right corner (

> http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/changing-highlighting-level-for-the-current-file.html

)

**solution 4:** Cleaning out the system caches
To clean out the system caches:

On the main menu, choose **File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.** The Invalidate Caches message appears informing you that the caches will be invalidated and rebuilt on the next start. Use buttons in the dialog to invalidate caches, restart PhpStorm or both.

It is important to note the following:

- The files are not actually deleted until PhpStorm restarts.
- Opening and closing a project does not result in deleting any files.